# Filemaker Pro and Import.IO. How to import into FMP using Import.IO API?

Tags: xml, excel, xslt, filemaker, import.io

I have a nice web scraper in Import.IO and I want to set up automatic uploads from Import.IO into Filemaker Pro. I've spent months on this and I have no idea why it does not work.
Here is what I've done.
I won't go into the Import.IO stuff in detail, as in the end you have options to export in Excel, CSV, JSON, or using RESTful type technology which is what I want, via their API.
I've got my API, but when I import it into FMP, I always get this error

> "Error in line 1, char 1".

The stylesheet I've developed by hand is as follows:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Input" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Result Number" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Widget" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Data Origin" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Result Row" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Source Page URL" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Link" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="f8" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="f9" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="f10" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Address" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Price" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Availability" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Baths" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Beds" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Cars" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="New" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Open" TYPE="TEXT"/>
                <FIELD EMPTYOK="YES" MAXREPEAT="1" NAME="Agent" TYPE="TEXT"/>
            </METADATA>
            <RESULTSET>
                <ROW>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@input"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Result Number"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Widget"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Data Origin"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Result Row"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Source Page URL"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Link"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@f8"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@f9"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@f10"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Address"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Price"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Availability"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Baths"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Beds"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Cars"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@New"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Open"/></DATA></COL>
                    <COL><DATA><xsl:value-of select="@Agent"/></DATA></COL>
                </ROW>
            </RESULTSET>
        </FMPXMLRESULT> 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Questions:

1. How can I validate the above stylesheet against my data from Import.IO? I am happy to export it into Excel and test it from there.
2. Is there anything obviously wrong with the stylesheet above?
3. How can I put in here my API so someone else can test it in FMP?

FMP is a great system, but it's RESTful documentation is poor to crap to be honest. I have very little knowledge of web services, XML importing and RESTful protocols, so any other suggestions will be appreciated.

Thank you

**UPDATE**
Look guys I am not an XML guru or know anything really about XSL and stylesheets.
All I want is to be able to use an API from Import.IO to import data into Filemaker Pro. It's as simple as that!
I don't want to have to create a server, or a translator, or fancy stuff.
I would have thought that the Import.IO API would have been enough, and their videos imply this (not with FMP though).
So unless you guys care to step into my world, create a free Import.IO account, create an API and test it with FMP, then I really don't know what more I can give you. I am a total beginner at XML, XSL, and RESTful what ever it's called.
I am not asking you to spoon feed me either. I just need a proper example of how to make this work - if it works at all!
The only alternative I have is to export my web scraped data from Import.IO as a CSV and import it directly into a temporary table into FMP. So easy, but so MANUAL!
There must be an automatic solution to this.
Thank you

Comment: Re your update: I can help you with your XSLT - **if** you post the raw XML received as the result of calling the API. I am afraid I don't have the time to experiment with the API on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything obviously wrong with the stylesheet above?

Yes, several things. First, names in XML cannot contain spaces - so when you call for:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Result Number"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Data Origin"/>
```

that will produce an error.

Next, your context is the root `/` node, which cannot have *attributes*. As a result, **all** your `DATA` elements will be empty.

That doesn't mean that the error you report is caused by any of these flaws. It probably isn't.

> How can I put in here my API so someone else can test it in FMP?

Doesn't your API have a URL?

Comment: thanks for those tips. Yes the API is a URL, but wouldn't that be a security issue for us and our Import.io account?

Comment: @Fernando68 I don't know enough about import.io to answer that. Do they not offer a "sandbox" for testing? If not, can you not create such "sandbox" account for yourself? -- From the very little I have read, all they do is reformat a publicly available site - so publishing a URL to the result is no more revealing than the URL to the original site. But that's just a guess on my part.

Comment: Wow, did you really spend months on this? It could be solved in an hour or so. Personally I would not use XSL in this case since it´s like shooting flies with a howitzer. A simple (and to FileMaker native!) PHP script that cURLs the API and uses simpelXML to render the importable XML is a super simple, easily maintained and time saving solution. If you haven´t solved this yet, go PHP/simpleXML and be done this afternoon...

Comment: Yup. Installing FileMaker sever with default settings installs PHP. If it is the work "native" that you don´t like we can change it to something else, non-the-less PHP ships with all FileMaker Servers and are configured and ready for use after installing. It is my opinion that it offers way faster development for small tasks like the one requested by OP. I´m not saying that PHP is better then XSL, but easier for most to understand. If truly month was spent on this it is my recommendation that a new strategy is used...

Comment: You are assuming there is FileMaker Server installed here. And that it is being used for CWP/PHP. And that OP knows how to use both. I see no basis for any one of these assumptions. -- OTOH, importing XML **is** native to the FileMaker Pro application, the XSLT language is better suited for XML processing that **anything** else, and it can be learned in an hour or two (at last the parts that are relevant to the task at hand).

Comment: @KalleSamuelsson Thank you for that tip, but I am not running a FMP server, and this is on the Mac. I am simply running FMpro as a desktop application, and I am trying to get it to run an API that I thought was based on REST based technologies. However, I will read that link and correct the errors in the XML and see how far it takes me.

Comment: @KalleSamuelsson please read my update above. I am begging here!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are passing a single node with 19 attributes your stylesheet does not make sense. Which brings the second question - why some of your attributes have spaces. I don't now Import.IO but this will break general XML rules.

You don't validate your stylesheet, you should validate your XML. Stylesheet is either works or it does not - you just test it.

Try to post your sample XML with the help on your stylesheet.

FIleMaker is not a RESTful application, I don't know what documentation you are referring to. If you need to use RESTful look at restfm:

http://www.restfm.com/

Comment: "*FIleMaker is not a RESTful application*" I don't think that's relevant to the question: OP wants to import from a RESTful API, not to provide one.

Comment: I appreciate that, but the comment was in response to OP complaining about FileMaker "bad" RESTful  documentation.

Comment: @NicolaiKant XML does not make sense? Well please help me make sense of it. The FMP documentation on *their* XML standard is rubbish. There is nothing to explain how to avoid the first 2 rows of data for example. What makes sense to you?

Comment: Sorry, but still does not make sense. Why do you want to avoid first two rows of data? Do not export them or delete them from your import. It is not FIleMaker XML does not make sense it is your XSLT. Please reread Michael's reply, your are mapping to attributes with spaces, so you incoming XML will not pass standard XML validation.